# Is there any way to return the AM/PM to my status bar?

Tags: samsung, clock, 9.0-pie, verizon, samsung-galaxy-note-9

This is specific to a carrier-locked (VZW) Samsung Galaxy Note 9 running v9.0 Pie. Samsung decided to take away the AM/PM indication in the status bar clock, likely to save space for the "hole punch". They didn't even see fit to make it an optional toggle. My web searches have returned no result apart that people other than just myself rely on it being there. Does anyone here have a solution of any kind? The key here is the ability to note the meridiem at a glance from any screen

Also: Yes, I know the "Always On" screen has faces that include AM/PM. That doesn't quite work for what I need.

And **please**, don't respond with "why can't you just look out the window?" like somebody in every other forum I've searched. Some of us don't *have* windows or operate on a normal human schedule.

Comment: Don't see a "AM/PM" indicator on the status bar clock on my Pixel 2 running Android 9.0. Personally use 24 hr clock format. Did find: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112787369#comment17 which makes it seem like an existing issue with Android 9.